# The difference between the Spring Framework and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

It is better to choose for the first time: Spring Framework or Spring Boot?

Comment: Go to http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ and read the introductory paragraph. If that's something you would like, choose boot. If that's something you don't want, don't use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spring Framework is a **core** of all other Spring IO [projects](https://spring.io/platform)

Of course Spring Boot is based on Spring Framework, too, and provides the extension **configuration on convention** model, if say it in two words.

And I'd say it won't hurt to use Boot for all your applications and don't just rely on Spring Framework. Anyway I'm not sure that for your applications it will just enough to use Inversion of Control. I guess you are going to use other Enterprise features, like Security, MVC, JPA, Hadoop etc. And Boot allows to simplify the configurations for most of them.

All other useful info you can find on [Spring IO](https://spring.io/guides)